# How can I use a Django template variable inside a HTML tag attribute?

Tags: python, html, django

Im trying to make a wikipedia clone for studying purposes, 'encyclopedia' is my django app name and {{entry}} its a wiki page. My code line looks like this : `<a href="{% url 'encyclopedia:{{entry}}'%}"`>,
I searched in google but cant find anyone talking about django variables inside HTML tag atributtes.

When I run my code i see this error:

```
`NoReverseMatch at /
Reverse for '{{entry}}' not found. '{{entry}}' is not a valid view function or pattern name. `
```

Comment: Exactly what is entry, can you share the `path` you want to use?

Comment: bro, thank you for answering this, i guess im going to solve my problem for myself because your question made me think of something in my code. If I need anymore help i will coment here, but thank you anyway.

Comment: Since you did not share the path you want to target, how are people supposed to help...

Comment: We can't see the for loop in your question. post the full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're facing is because you're using Django template variables inside the {% url %} template tag incorrectly. In Django templates, you don't need to use double curly braces ({{ }}) inside the {% url %} tag.

Here's how you should structure your link:

```
<a href="{% url 'encyclopedia:entry' entry=entry %}">
```

Comment: We can't see the for loop in your question. post the full code.